# Getting values from attributes in xml

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

Given the following:

```
<Query>
<Where>
<Eq>
<FieldRef Name=\"ID\" />
<Value Type=\"Title\">
 1 
</Value>
</Eq>
</Where>
</Query>
```

How can I, via using XElement (LINQ to XML):

1) Select the title word (to change it)?

2) Get the 1 value (to change it)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
string xml = @"<Query>
<Where>
<Eq>
<FieldRef Name=""ID"" />
<Value Type=""Title"">
 1 
</Value>
</Eq>
</Where>
</Query>";

var el = XElement.Parse(xml);
var value = el.Descendants("Value").FirstOrDefault();
value.Attribute("Type").Value = "abcdef";
value.Value = "ghijkl";

string newXml = el.ToString();
```